# Debian hibernate problem PM: Swap header not found

Tags: power-management, swap

I have Debian 6 2.6.32-5-amd64 on netbook. With `pm-utils` Sleep works but hibernate fails with error: `PM: Swap header not found!`. Swap was enabled using ubuntu tutorial after installation - this is probably the key but can't find working solution.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it work by creating swap as separate disk partition and by editing initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.

Comment: I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -pmedium uswsusp` and it allowed me to select the swapfile, fixing the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

You don't have a recognizable swap partition. Check that your swap partition is active: run `cat /proc/swaps` to see what swap space is in use.

This may be a symptom of trying to hibernate to a swap file. See e.g. [Ubuntu bug #313724](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/313724). Some hibernation methods accept swap files, but this depends on both the hibernation method and the kernel version, and it looks like yours can't cope with a swap file. Some versions of `pm-utils` [can hibernate to a file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file_resuming); you need to configure the system to pass the proper `resume_offset` argument when booting back into the hibernated system.

If you created a swap partition with a more recent operating system, or had encrypted swap before but no longer, you may need to reinitialize the swap partition. Run `mkswap` on the block device corresponding to the partition (e.g. `mkswap /dev/sdz99` — make sure that you get the name and number right, since otherwise this will overwrite one of your data partitions).